# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in Angularjs 1.6.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have to dropdown lists and want to populate the second list on the basis of selected value in the first list. I encountered a problem in populating the first list. I use getCurrentSessionCourses() method of Course Service to get data from the server and populate the first list from that data. The first list populates within the for loop. If for loop executes before the response of server then *i < $scope.Courses.length* has undefined value. *Sometimes data came before the execution of for loop and sometimes data came after the execution of for loop*. Below is my AddStudentController.js and related HTML

```js
   

 (function(){

     var myApp = angular.module("myApp");

        var AddStudentController = function ($scope,StudentService,CourseService) {
        
         var onCourses = function (data) {
                var result = [];        
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Courses.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                      if (data[j].IdCourse ===  $scope.Courses[i].idCourse) {
                            if (result.indexOf(data[j]) === -1) {
                                result.push(data[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                 $scope.courses = result;
                $scope.selectedCourse = result[0];

                var IdCourse = $scope.selectedCourse.IdCourse;
                var IdSessionCourse = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Courses.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.Courses[i].idCourse === IdCourse) {
                        IdSessionCourse = $scope.Courses[i].idSessionCourse;
                    }
                };
                CourseService.getCourseClasses(IdSessionCourse).then(function (classes) { 
                $scope.classes = classes;
                $scope.selectedClass = classes[0];
                });
        
        CourseService.getCurrentSessionCourses().then(function (courses) { $scope.Courses = courses });
        CourseService.courses().then(onCourses); 
        };
        
        myApp.controller("AddStudentController", AddStudentController)
        
    }());

////Below is CourseService.js

    (function () {
    
        var CourseService = function ($http) {
    
            var urlBase = 'api/CoursesAPI';
    
            var getCurrentSessionCourses = function () {
                return $http.get("api/CoursesAPI/GetCurrentSessionCourses")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
    
    return {
     getCurrentSessionCourses: getCurrentSessionCourses,
    };
            };
     var module = angular.module("myApp");
        module.factory("CourseService", CourseService);
    }());
```

```html
 

<div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Select Course</label>
          <select ng-model="selectedCourse" ng-change="change()" class="formcontrol" 
        ng-options="course.IdCourse as course.Name for course in courses"> 
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Select Class</label>
         <select ng-model="selectedClass" class="form-control" ng-options="class.idClass as class.className +' : '+class.campusName  for class in classes"></select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post your service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `CourseService.courses()` after the `CourseService.getCurrentSessionCourses()` in this way:

```
CourseService.getCurrentSessionCourses().then(function (courses) { 
    $scope.Courses = courses;
    CourseService.courses().then(onCourses);
});
```

In this way you will be sure that `$scope.Courses` has some value when you try to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `$scope.Courses = []`.

When angular is rendering the page, It will not find any `$scope.Courses` object until you assign your response to `$scope.Courses`, thus throwing

> $scope.Courses.length has undefined value

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
    $scope.Courses = []; // Add this line
    var AddStudentController = function ($scope,StudentService,CourseService) {

     var onCourses = function (data) {
```

...